# Kubernetes: Disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, configmap

An existing nginx ingress named `nginx-proxy` running on the K8 cluster.

Now, there is a requirement from the Dev team to disable TLS 1.0, 1.1 support.

Upon searching, I could see [this solution](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/) using configmap.

Do you think applying/creating a new configmap as follows to an existing nginx ingress helps me to resolve the issue?

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy
data:
  ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
```

Adding a new configmap like that to an existing nginx ingress breaks anything?. Because this is for the production website.

A piece of advice would be really helpful.

Comment: try applying it on your dev or qa stage cluster and see if it breaks? if you dont have one. at least in your dev/qa namespace and access dev stage applications via this nginx?

Comment: Testing this setup in non-production environment is a first thing you should do. If it breaks you'll have logs that indicate what went wrong. You can include those logs in this question, so the community will be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: Added this configmap and applied but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

> To provide the most secure baseline configuration possible,
>
> nginx-ingress defaults to using TLS 1.2 and 1.3 only, with a [secure set of TLS ciphers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#ssl-ciphers). <sup>[[source](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#default-tls-version-and-ciphers)]</sup>

It seems ingress-nginx uses TLS *1.2* and *1.3* **only** by default. The snippet you added to your question can be used to enable older TLS versions - like *1.0* and *1.1*.

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  ssl-ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA"
  ssl-protocols: "TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
```

<sup>[[source](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#legacy-tls)]</sup>

You can check which versions of TLS (and ciphers) are enabled by issuing

```text
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <ingress-nginx>
```

replace `<ingress-nginx>` with your ingress IP.

Comment: Thank you. Am I supposed to simply apply this configmap or should I additionally need to do anything on the responsible nginx-ingress for the website?.

Comment: If you want TLS 1.0 and 1.1 disabled, do not apply this configmap. This is just an example of how to enable them. By default older versions of TLS should be disabled.

Comment: ok, so I can exclude `TLSv1 TLSv1.1` and then apply the configmap, correct?

Comment: Again, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 should be disabled by default, you can, but you don't have to apply this configmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this official document or disabling the TLS 1.0

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  ssl-ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
  ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
```

You need to update the ciphers also as perversion instead of using the default one.

You can try with the above **configmap**.

Also, I would recommend updating the SSL/TLS cert if you using in ingress.

If you are using the cert-manager please try deleting the secret which containing the SSL/TLS cert for ingress endpoint and try getting the cert again using the cert-manager once.

Comment: Thank you Harsh. Am I supposed to simply apply this configmap or should I additionally need to do anything on the responsible nginx-ingress for the website?.

Comment: just apply the config map and restart the pod of Nginx controller as mentioned take look at the cert tls/ssl you are using you might need to change it.