# How to disable TLS in nginx ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I was trying to enable TLS in nginx ingress controller. I followed below link and I am able to access my service through https.

https://devopscube.com/configure-ingress-tls-kubernetes/

There are only two extra configuration is needed:

- Create a secret resource with self signed certificate.
- Pass the secret resource name in ingress resource file as:

  tls:

  - hosts:

    - localhost
      secretName: my-tls-secret

Now, I want to access my resource with http not with https. But I am not able to revert the behavior's even after reverting the changes.

Could you please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [document](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/):

> By default the controller redirects HTTP clients to the HTTPS port 443 using a 308 Permanent Redirect response if TLS is enabled for that Ingress.
> This can be disabled globally using ssl-redirect: "false" in the NGINX [config map](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/), or per-Ingress with the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" annotation in the particular resource.

You can also refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525698/kubernetes-disable-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nginx-ingress)  if you want to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on nginx ingress.